# When did Krypton explode?

Tags: dc, superman

Is it ever specified when did Krypton explode considering Earth time?

I read that Superman took about three years to reach Earth, but I think it was considering the time at the capsule (which would change based on its speed).

Comment: 1903.. Just before launching Superman into Space, his father told his mother about recent invention of Mankind.. The Airplane.

Comment: About 20-25 years before Clark made his first public appearance as Superman.  Unless the ship cryogenically froze him, or sent him through a wormhole, or...y'know what?  It happened a while back.  It happened when the plot needs it to have happened.  Or, of course, "When Superman was a newborn baby."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In the DCnU reboot:

**27.1 years ago.**

DC Comics teamed with Neil DeGrasse Tyson to find a star that would resemble Rao. [In Action Comics #14, the light from Krypton's explosion was supposed to be visible from Earth.](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-57545886-1/neil-degrasse-tyson-locates-supermans-home-planet/) This news is related courtesy of CNET on November 6, 2012.

> Tyson teamed with DC Comics to track down a Krypton-like system that matches hints from the comics. He found a fitting red dwarf in the constellation Corvus (the crow) in the southern sky, a mere 27.1 light years from Earth.Tyson even gets a cameo in Action Comics #14, "Star Light, Star Bright," when Superman makes a visit to the astrophysicist's planetarium.